# Issue with fraction multiplication, everything being considered as being the denominator

Tags: fractions

I am working in the Overleaf IDE, and simply trying to write down some fraction multiplications. As a simple example, let's consider the expression to be (a/b)(c/d).

Within my \begin{displaymath} environment, my code is this:

```
\frac{a}{b} \frac{c}{d}
```

Yet what comes out is **a times (blank over b times (c over d))**. Sorry if that's a confusing way of writing it. I've included a picture of the output.
I've also tried writing the code with parentheses around the two fractions, but the same error occurs. I just want to write down some simple fractions, can anyone point out what might be causing this issue?

[image: fraction_error]

Comment: the input you show would not (with the usual definitions) produce the output you show. Please (always) include a complete small document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that you have

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  
\frac{a}{b} \frac{c}{d}

\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You need to remove the blank lines.

Never ignore errors, Latex reports

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.6 
    
?
```

After *any* error the PDF is not intended to be usable. (a red circle on overleaf)

Comment: Yes, yes you are exactly correct. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hi, truly I have thinked to \over like in LibreOffice or the old OpenOffice. I hope that you read my comment. Now I have removed my answer: I had not understood also the question. +1